# How do I make the menubar a different color on my dev/staging sites

Tags: developer, menu

Wouldn't it be nice if I could visually distinguish my various dev/staging sites with a different menubar color for each one?

Is this possible in CiviCRM and if so what version?

Answer (score 9):

As of CiviCRM v5.12.1 the menubar color is a configurable setting.

On your main site you can change the color via the UI by visiting **Administer -> Customize Data & Screens -> Display Preferences**.

[image: Menubar configuration]

Since this preference is stored in a system setting, you can override it on your various dev/staging sites by adding a line like this to `civicrm.settings.php`:

```
$civicrm_setting['CiviCRM Preferences']['menubar_color'] = '#800000';
```